# Delegate arguments causing ambiguous overloaded functions resolution

Tags: c#, .net, generics, compiler-errors, overload-resolution

I ran into an odd compilation issue while I was implementing a simple timing utility class.

I implemented the following class that would allow wrapping calls to functions with timing related measurement information.

```
public static class TimeMeasument
{
    public static void LogRunTime<T>(Action<T> func, T arg)
    {
        Stopwatch timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        try { func(arg); }
        finally { Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time {0} ms", timer.ElapsedMilliseconds); }
    }

    public static TResult LogRunTime<TResult, T>(Func<T, TResult> func, T arg)
    {
        Stopwatch timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        try { return func(arg); }
        finally { Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time {0} ms", timer.ElapsedMilliseconds); }
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that when I went to use the function I received an `Ambiguous function call` compiler error when trying to call functions that have a return value.

```
// Example function
string SayHello(string name)  { return "Hello " + name; }

// Compiler error 
// Ambiguous call between the following methods
// LogRunTime<T>(Action<T> func, T arg)
// and LogRunTime<TResult, T>(Func<T,TResult> func, T arg)
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
string x = TimeMeasument.LogRunTime(SayHello, "Joe");
```

I need to explicitly create a `Func<T,U>` for the function to remove the ambiguity.

```
// Compiles fine
Func<string, string> func = SayHello;
string s = TimeMeasument.LogRunTime(func, "Joe");
```

I was wondering why the `Action<T>` overload is being considered by the compiler as an option. I know that the generic type parameter for Action is satisfied by the second argument passed to `LogRunTime` but the function `SayHello` is not convertible to an Action. Doing so will result in the following error.

```
// Compiler error
// SayHello(string) has the wrong return type
//-------------------------------
Action<string> action = SayHello;
```

Can anyone shed some light on why the `Action<T>` overload is considered as a valid target?

Is there any other way of getting around this issue without explicitly creating/casting each function call?

Comment: From the linked duplicate answer it looks like the best solution to address this compiler error is to pass a lambda functions instead. Like this:  `TimeMeasument.LogRunTime(y => SayHello(y), "Joe");`